# Layout for 2 UILabels on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

I wish to have 2 labels on custom table view cell. First label should be on left 15 points away from left margin and 2nd label should be on right 15 points away from right margin. It can grow internally. Since the label is not going to display lots of data, it surely won't overlap on each other.

I am using stack view. Below are the images for my custom xib file. Number of lines for both the label is set to 1. When I launch, I see a blank cell without the labels. What is missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

***EDIT:*** Adding more details. I updated distribution on UIStackView to Fill Equally and updated alignment for 2nd label i.e start time label to right. I am seeing the data on the cell now, but 2nd label is not getting aligned to right.

[image]

[image]
**Code in cellForRow:**

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "displayStartTime") as! ScheduleDisplayStartTimeCustomCell
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.gray
cell.titleLabel.text = "Start"
cell.timeLabel.text = startTime
return cell
```

This is how it looks now after the edit:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code of your cellForRowAt method.

Comment: @NicolasElPapu - Added more screenshots and code in cell for row. I am setting number of lines on the label in xib itself. I updated distribution to fill equally on stackview now and am seeing the labels on cell, but text on my 2nd cell is not getting right aligned.

Comment: You can try this line : cell.timeLabel.textAlignment = .right

Comment: @NicolasElPapu - I just now added that line in cellForRow and didn't work. :(

Comment: It's probably because of your stack view, you are filling it proportionally. In your question you say the left label and right label should be 15 points away from left/right respectively; but you set those constraints for the stack view not the labels.

Comment: In my edit, I updated stackview to fill equally. The labels should be 15 points away from margin i.e. left should be 15pts away from left margin and right should be 15 pts away from right margin. The labels are being placed right after I edited the stackview to fill equally, just the text is not getting aligned to right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Storyboard solution:**

You can select the distribution for the StackView to equal spacing in the storyboard, with the default spacing value. The Labels only need the height contraint after that (or you could set the height for the StackView), and will be positioned to the sides of the StackView.

[Resulting cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjLNE.png)

The text alignment in the Label won’t matter, as the Label will be only as wide as needed.

Comment: I had done exact same thing in my edited post. On the storyboard am seeing label text on the right just like the link you posted, but on the actual app, I am seeing the text on the left. I tried setting alignment in the code, but still it's on the left.

Comment: In your edit I see Fill Equally, which is not the same as Equal Spacing (be sure not to have it set with some large spacing values, 0 is fine) and constrained on leading and trailing edges. Also as someone else suggested, setting temporarily background color to red/blue etc. on the labels might help you see, how the labels themselves are laid out.

Comment: I also tried it your way, with fill equally and right alignment of the text in the label and it works fine as well, as it should. So there must be something else in the code

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I think I didn't notice the option of Equal Spacing and was thinking both are the same. Updating distribution to equal spacing worked for me. Had to set text alignment to right in this case too, but it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not use storyboards that much but I know this works.
First you have to register the cell in your viewDidLoad:

```swift
tableView.register(ScheduleDisplayStartTimeCustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "displayStartTime")
```

Then you can programmatically create a custom cell like this:

```swift
class ScheduleDisplayStartTimeCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    let startLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        label.textAlignment = .left
        return label
    }()
    
    let timeLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        label.textAlignment = .right
        return label
    }()

    
    func setupView() {
        addSubview(startLabel)
        addSubview(timeLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            startLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            startLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 15),
           
            timeLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -15),
            timeLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor)
        ])
        
        selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.gray
    }
    
}
```

And finally you would set your cells like this :

```swift
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "displayStartTime") as! ScheduleDisplayStartTimeCustomCell
        cell.startLabel.text = "Start"
        cell.timeLabel.text = startTime
        
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: I will give this a try. One question, for timeLabel, there are no numberOfLines set in your code, is it intentional?

Comment: Oops, no its not, i forgot. You can edit the label attributes there. (I updated the answer too) Also make sure you don't get errors for re using identifiers because i used your cell class name and the same identifier for the cell.

Comment: Great. I will give it a try tonight and will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I tried you solution and it worked for me. Thanks for sharing the code! Since I am keeping the xib files in the project, I will use @Ardno's answer.

Comment: Okay sorry i couldn't help you with the storyboard. But you got it working now. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

I have had similar issues in the past, the best solution I found it to assign a BackgroundColor to the labels (Blue, Red) and the StackView (Black). Then I see if the problem is with the constraints, or the UILabel text alignment properties.

Also, I noticed that you have an extension to UIViews, there may be something in there that is causing the problem.